# C# Mysql Error Check if token Exist

Tags: c#, mysql

Okay, so I want to check if the token exist. I do this and I get this
ERROR:  Unknown column 'WhatEverTokenIType' in 'where clause'
Ik the token doesn't exist i just want it to print that to the console as I have it below.

```
    public static async Task RedeemToken(CommandEventArgs e, string Token) {

        try {
            var Channel = e.Server.FindChannels("tokens").FirstOrDefault();
            var User = e.User;

            string Connection = "datasource=myip;port=3306;database=somedb;username=someuser;password=somepass;";
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE token = " + Token;

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader reader = null;

            conn.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int tokenExist = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (tokenExist > 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Token Exist");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Token Doesn't Exist");
            }
            while (reader.Read()) {
            }
            conn.Close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL would be something like `SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE token = someToken` - that's treating `someToken` as a *column name*, not a value.

You should use parameterized SQL instead of building the SQL dynamically, e.g.

```
// Include the parameter name (@token) in the SQL...
string query = "SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE token = @token";

// Then populate the parameter *value* in the parameter collection.
// Change the parameter type to match the token column, obviously.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@token", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = token;
```

Additionally, you should:

- Use `using` statements to ensure you close connections, commands etc properly
- Follow .NET and C# naming conventions, where parameters, local variables etc start with a lower case letter.
- Use asynchronous calls within an `async` method - currently the calling method is still going to block while you execute the query.
- Not call `ExecuteScalar()` in your code - you're already calling `ExecuteReader()`, and your query doesn't return a scalar value, so why would you call it?

Comment: okay, now i get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Clearout: Well without any more information than that, all I can do is point you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142